# Would it be possible to convert between data types using a string?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, types

Would it possible to convert between data types using a string? I'm writing a Azure function that receives the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": "1",
  "type": "int"
}
```

And I want return the "1" as int. What I have done so far:

```
dynamic body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(body as string);
```

The data class:

```
public class Data
{
    public string data { get; set; },
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you don't need `dynamic`, `ReadAsStringAsync` returns a string.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Wasn't me, I don't know why the DV. One tip though, I would suggest you don't use "data" to name everything and don't use "type" either.

Comment: Thank you, I will change to improve the readability o/.

Answer (score 1):

In your `"type"`, you should use fully qualified .net type names:

Example:

```
System.Int32
```

Once you have this, use the following way to convert it to `Type`

```
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(body as string);    
Type myType = Type.GetType(data.type);
var item = Convert.ChangeType(data.data, myType);
Console.WriteLine(item);
Console.WriteLine(item.GetType());
```

Comment: But won't this always get string because data.type will be always a string?

Comment: When `data.type = "System.Int32"`, the `item` will be of `Int32` type. Tested the code before posting

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm on my mobile phone. When I get in home I will test and accept your answer.